# Multiple variables with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

What I want to achieve is that click on dialog should alert 'color' variable defined by parent function, and only that one. Instead, if I first click on, say, RED, and then on, say, BLUE, and then on dialog 'blue', I have two alerts: 'red' and 'blue' instead of only 'blue' one.

HTML:

```
<div class='clickable' id='red'>RED</div>
<div class='clickable' id='green'>GREEN</div>
<div class='clickable' id='blue'>BLUE</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
    var color = $(this).attr('id');

    $('<div class="dialog">').html(color).dialog();

    $('body').on('click', '.dialog', function() {
        alert(color);
    });
});
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/DAcrK/).  Of course, I could just save that variable and the read it, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/VfYNF/):

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
    var color = $(this).attr('id');

    $('<div class="dialog" color="' + color + '">').html(color).dialog();
});


$('body').on('click', '.dialog', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('color'));
});
```

but maybe there is more elegant solution?

Comment: Your problem isn't the color, it's that you're attaching multiple handlers to .dialog. Basically if you click three times on each of the clickables you're attaching three handlers. Each handler fires the correct respective color, but all three are going to fire in response. the reason the second example works is because you're attaching the dialog handler only once. I think the latter approach is the right one to do what you want.

Comment: I would understand if 'color' variable was just replaced with each click, but there becomes more 'color' vars… strange =| Still, could 'color' vars in different handlers be somehow isolated from each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
  var color = $(this).attr('id');

  var dialog = $('<div class="dialog">');
  dialog.html(color).dialog();

  dialog.on('click', function() {
    console.log(color);
    alert(color);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hm, works perfectly so far… Will play a bit more with it, this may be a solution.

Comment: This should not work. Open more dialogs (they stack on each other on JSFiddle, but just move them and click old ones, they will show new color value).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
  var color = $(this).attr('id');

  var dialog = $('<div class="dialog">');
  dialog.html(color).dialog();

  dialog.on('click', (function(color) { return function() {
    console.log(color);
    alert(color);
  }; })(color));
});
```

This should work will old dialogs, too.

Comment: But the question you asked is now solved (the var is isolated). Problem with the code of JSFiddle is that there are many handlers and all gets activated at the time one dialog is clicked. You should somehow properly cleanup dialogs/their .on handlers. They are stacking up.